# Default URL for category dropdown select option

Tags: categories, redirect, forms, select, customization

I have a dropdown menu for my categories:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" id="catform">
    <?php
        $parent = get_cat_ID("Pictures");
        $select = wp_dropdown_categories("child_of=".$parent."&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&echo=0&show_option_none=Select...");
        $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
        echo $select;
    ?>
</form>
```

This automatically goes to the category page in question when an option is chosen.

This is working great, except for one minor detail...the default option.

I have a default option called `Select...`, but what I didn't realize is when you choose that option something is returned. On normal pages, nothing seems to happen, but that's because `Select...` is chosen by default. On the category page (`category.php`), if you choose `Select...` you get redirected to: http://myurl.com/?cat=-1.

Is there any way when someone chooses `Select...` the page does not submit the form?

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: After some research I discovered that `option_none_value` defaults to: `-1`, so because I didn't declare this, that's why that's working that way...I'd still just like it to not do anything when chosen...is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

As I was looking for a fix I ran across this article: https://andrux.net/add-empty-option-to-wp_dropdown_categories/

This is very close to what I was looking for, so I tweaked it.

The only thing I did to the form was remove the `show_option_none=Select...`

The form code:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" id="catform">
    <?php
        $parent = get_cat_ID("Pictures");
        $select = wp_dropdown_categories("child_of=".$parent."&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&echo=0");
        $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
        echo $select;
    ?>
</form>
```

Now, this goes into `functions.php`:

```
function add_extra_blank_option( $html ) {
    $needle = '<option';
    $replace_with = '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select...</option><option';

    /* replace the very first '<option' text with the blank option tag */
    $pos = strpos( $html, $needle );
    if ( $pos !== false ) {
        $html = substr_replace( $html, $replace_with, $pos, strlen( $needle ) );
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'add_extra_blank_option' );
```

This adds an extra blank option, but I wanted my new option to say "Select...", so "Select..." has been added in-between the `option` tags.

I also wanted my new option to be showing by default, so I added `selected="selected"` to my `option` tag.

Finally, I wanted the option to be disabled, so that the option could not be selected, so I added `disabled` to my `option` tag.

That's it, that's all there is to it :-)

Thanks,
Josh